# Array passed to constructor function in Javascript isn't modified in calling content

Tags: javascript

I have the following module that is imported in the calling context:

```
function Controls(elem, viewMatrix) {

    var xD, yD;

    this.ppdX = 10;
    this.ppdY = 10;

    this.state = 0;
    var dx = 0;
    var dy = 0;

    function getXY(evt) {
        var x = evt.pageX - elem.offsetLeft;
        var y = evt.pageY - elem.offsetTop;
        return [x, y];
    }

    function onDown(evt) {
        this.state = 1;
        [xD, yD] = getXY(evt);
    }

    function onUp(evt) {
        this.state = 0;
        [dx, dy] = [0, 0];
    }

    function onMove(evt) {
        if (!this.state) return;
        var [x, y] = getXY(evt);
        [dx, dy] = [x - xD, y - yD];
    }

    this.updateView = function () {
        viewMatrix = Mtx.mult(viewMatrix, Mtx.rotY(-Mtx.DtoR * dx / this.ppdX));
        viewMatrix = Mtx.mult(viewMatrix, Mtx.rotX(-Mtx.DtoR * dy / this.ppdY));
    }

    elem.addEventListener("mousedown", onDown.bind(this));
    elem.addEventListener("mouseup", onUp.bind(this));
    elem.addEventListener("mousemove", onMove.bind(this));
}

export default Controls;
```

The calling context goes as follows:

```
import Controls from './js/controls.module.js';
...

viewMatrix = Mtx.makeIdent(4, 4);
controls = new Controls(renderer.domElement, viewMatrix);
...

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if (controls.state) {
        controls.updateView();
        ...
        console.log(viewMatrix);
    }

...

}
```

where viewMatrix is an 4x4 array defined like so:

```
viewMatrix = [[...],[...],[...],[...]];
```

I can see that while viewMatrix is changed inside updateView() call, it is not changing in the calling context. Arrays are supposed to be passed by reference, is it not true in this case?

I know I can return the matrix from updateView() to the calling context and overwrite viewMatrix there, but I'd like to know why is it not updating and maybe there is another way to write this code so it updates by itself?

EDIT code for multiplication:

```
    mult(A, B) {
        var C = [];
        var Ar = A.length, Ac = A[0].length;
        var Br = B.length, Bc = B[0].length;
        if (Ac != Br) {
            console.log("mult(): dimentions mismatch");
            return C;
        }
        for (let ar = 0; ar < Ar; ar++) {
            C[ar] = [];
            for (let bc = 0; bc < Bc; bc++) {
                C[ar][bc] = 0;
                for (let ac = 0; ac < Ac; ac++) {
                    C[ar][bc] += A[ar][ac] * B[ac][bc]
                }
            }
        }
        return C;
    },
```

Comment: We might need to see how `mult()` is implemented, but in the statements `viewMatrix = Mtx.mult(...)`, it looks like the value of `viewMatrix` is just being overwritten, which would mean your original matrix object would not be affected by the statements. (Again though, it depends on how `mult()` is implemented.)

Comment: You could do something like `const temp = Mtx.mult(...)`, and then copy the elements of `temp` to `viewMatrix`. (This is a separate issue, but keep in mind that this sort of repeated modification of a matrix can cause numerical error to accumulate, which may become noticeable over time.)

Comment: Just use `this.viewMatrix` in `updateView`, and do `console.log(controls.viewMatrix)`. *Don't* attempt to have the controls manipulate the global `viewMatrix`, it should be an instance property.

Comment: @user1481126: Obviously you can do whatever you want, but there might be arguments (e.g. based on the 'separation of concerns' principle or the MVC pattern) for not making the matrix a property of the 'controls' object. Another option (which would probably be better than my previous suggestion) would be to make the view matrix (and any other similar data) a property of an object that the 'controls' object stores a reference to. Then you could overwrite the matrix as you're doing currently, while still being able to access it from elsewhere, independently of the 'controls' object.

Comment: @scg: thank you, your last suggestion solved my problem, since view matrix is a property of a camera object, I can pass it to controls and work from there. I'll accept it as an answer if you make one.